# Can I start atom from my ubuntu on windows terminal?

Tags: shell, ubuntu-16.04, atom-editor

I have been following this class which has instructed me to open atom through my ubuntu terminal with the command "atom ." but it prints "command not found"

I know now that the ubuntu system and windows system run independently of each other, but still have no clue how to make it work.Here is the error

```
No command 'atom' found, did you mean:
 Command 'atrm' from package 'at' (main)
 Command 'atoms' from package 'horae' (multiverse)
 Command 'atom4' from package 'atom4' (universe)
 Command 'atobm' from package 'x11-apps' (main)
 Command 'atop' from package 'atop' (universe)
atom: command not found
```

Comment: Ubuntu does not come preinstalled with atom. You must download it first.

Comment: @Perplexabot i have it installed on my system already though there is no way i can start it this way

Comment: What happens when you execute the following command in an Ubuntu terminal: `ls -l /usr/bin/atom`?

Comment: @Perplexabot ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/atom': No such file or directory

Comment: Hm. How are you accessing Ubuntu? USB boot? Virtual Machine? Full install? I ask because the message you got back in the terminal most likely means you don't have it installed. If you are on a USB boot of Ubuntu and rebooted, unless you have it set up properly, your installed programs and files will be wiped.

Comment: @Perplexabot virtual machine, well can you consider the ubuntu on windows app a virtual machine?

Comment: Try to install again.

Answer (score 1):

Install again if you have to (there is no hurt in doing so).

Try this link: [atom install](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/).

In summary, this is what the link says to do. (When executing these commands in your terminal, look to see if you get any output back. Observe if the terminal spits out errors.)

First in a terminal copy and paste the below then hit enter:

```
wget -qO - https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then copy and paste the below into a term and hit enter:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list'
```

Then this:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get install atom
```

Finally, see if you are able to open atom:

```
atom .
```

Comment: Now it doesnt show me command not found but nothing happens it just goes to another command line

Comment: Interesting. Ok. Reading [this](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/11712) it may be that atom-beta has a fix for the problem. Try running this command first in your terminal to uninstall atom `sudo apt-get remove atom` then install the beta version by running this command `sudo apt-get install atom-beta`. Then, once again see if you can start atom by running `atom .`

Comment: I navigated into the folder I wanted to open in atom then typed  `atom .`

Answer (score -1):

Another way is, to try the following command

```
snap run atom
```

If the above command works for you, you can make an alias

```
alias atom='snap run atom'
```